# AGPBI Error showing while building the app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[**Hi Whenever i tried lots of time to rectify the error.But always gradle fail. I searched so many stackoverflow with same issue still not getting any success. Help me out**][1]

> Blockquote

AGPBI:

```
{  
   "kind":"error",
   "text":"error: attribute \u0027com.app.xyz:menu_animationDelayPerItem\u0027 not found.",
   "sources":[  
      {  
         "file":"E:\XYZ\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_home.xml",
         "position":{  
            "startLine":130
         }
      }
   ],
   "original":"",
   "tool":"AAPT"
}AGPBI:{  
   "kind":"error",
   "text":"error: attribute \u0027com.app.xyz:menu_backgroundColor\u0027 not found.",
   "sources":[  
      {  
         "file":"         E:\XYZ\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_home.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

In your file `E:\XYZ\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_home.xml` you're referencing an attribute `menu_backgroundColor` which is not defined anywhere in your resources. 
Either remove that reference or add that color (?) to your resources.
If that doesn't solve your issue, post the contents of the `fragment_home.xml`.